# How to link many tables containing the same products with different columns and IDs

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have a number of tables from different suppliers containing information about the products they supply. The formats of the tables are different—different ids, different description, etc.—because each supplier stores separate information about their products. Some products in different tables might be the same but I don't know that at the time the rows are inserted; I have to go through them manually to determine which products are the same.

For example, consider the following tables ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/431c5c/1)):

```
CREATE TABLE A (
  id char(10)PRIMARY KEY,
  name char(16),
  color char(16),
  weight float
  );

CREATE TABLE B (
  id int(11) PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(60),
  color char(3)
  );
```

Each table may have different ID values, columns, and even values for the same column; e.g.:

```
Table A:
+------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------------+
|         ID |            NAME |         COLOR |          WEIGHT |
+------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------------+
| RFY-55-001 |  Wagon, Classic |           Red | 15.199999809265 |
| RFY-62-001 | Trike, My First |           Red |   8.60000038147 |
| RFY-64-001 |  Trike, 12 Inch |           Red |  15.39999961853 |
| SWN-35-001 | Trike, Roadster | Metallic Blue | 20.700000762939 |
| SWN-35-002 | Trike, Roadster |        Silver | 20.700000762939 |
| SWN-35-003 | Trike, Roadster |    Cherry Red | 20.700000762939 |
+------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------------+

Table B:
+-------+--------------------------------------------+--------+
|    ID |                                       NAME |  COLOR |
+-------+--------------------------------------------+--------+
| 10560 |                  Schwinn Roadster Tricycle |    BLU |
| 10685 |              Radio Flyer Classic Red Wagon | (null) |
| 10880 | Radio Flyer Classic Red Dual Deck Tricycle | (null) |
| 12008 |         Fisher-Price I Can Play Basketball | (null) |
+-------+--------------------------------------------+--------+
```

Supplier A stores a short product name, but includes detailed product information in additional columns. Supplier B stores a more detailed product name, but not much additional information. In both cases, the manufacturer's identity is mixed into some other field.

The rows are inserted automatically and I can't check each product before it is inserted. I can only go over them once in a while and update the links I find manually. For example, a little research shows that the Radio Flyer Classic Red Dual Deck Tricycle has a 12" front wheel and weighs 15.4 pounds, indicating that item `RFY-64-001` in Table A is the same product as item `10880` in Table B.

**What relations would I use to "link" rows in the different tables if they refer to the same product, sometime after inserting them, so that I would have one key for each unique product?**

The obvious solution would be to add a connecting table with my key and use triggers when inserting to the other tables. The problem with this solution is that the "sync" process becomes pretty manual, and prone to mistakes.

Comment: In addion to @HABO: (i) Why are the products in different tables in the first  place? (ii) Why/how are the tables different, if the products might be the same? (iii) Are they really potentially the same (e.g.: identical manufacturer but different distributor) or equivalent at best (diffent manufacturers)?

Comment: There are of course other columns, but they are not relevant, and might differ between the tables. For example they both have colors, but the contents of the color columns might not match. In addition, one table can have columns the other doesn't, like weight.

Comment: How do *you* tell, "products productA1 and productB2 are the exact same product"? How should the computer be able to reproduce this reasoning? You might find my earlier questions funny - to me, the answers could provide clues, how to align the different products programmatically…

Comment: I would really love to align the products programmatically.... but unfortunately it can't be done :) That's why I have to do that manually every once in a while.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Okay; so you have a number of tables originating from different sources, each implementing the same entity (Product) with their own logical structure. Any given record may exist in more than one table and your task is to reconcile these different data sources, using some manual process for determining which records are similar/identical across tables.

This sounds similar to a process that we go through at Cal/EPA to reconcile data from many different sources in creating a statewide inventory of air pollution. These sources include several different modeling teams, each working with a distinct set of input and output parameters; direct measurements from monitoring stations; annual reports from local and municipal agencies; and in some cases, data reported directly to us by individuals and businesses. This data comes to us in many different formats and much of it overlaps.

I won't bore you with the details of our reconciliation process, but I can tell you some of the things I've learned from it and suggest an approach that may work for you.

First, putting together overlapping data that exists in many different formats *sucks*. Our jobs would be much easier if everyone just used the same table structures and stayed out of each other's way. That said, this is the reality we have to deal with; this is why we have jobs. Different organizations and individuals operate differently, period, and most of the time you won't have the power to change the way they operate.

You need a plan, or else mistakes will be made—not occasional mistakes, but *constant* ones. One broad approach you can take is: I will accept data from all these sources, in all these formats and put it into a staging database, where I will manipulate and aggregate and chop and slap and maim the data as necessary to fit it into my shiny, well-behaved database where there's only one physical model and everything is wonderful. I can then forget about all the unspeakable things I did to the data to fit it in there in the first place, and life will be wonderful... until I have to do it all over again. This is called **ETL**, which stands for **Extract, Transform, Load**—or possibly Entrap, Torture, Lobotomize depending on how much fun you're having. You can [read about it on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) if you like (or [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/etl), or [here on DBA.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etl), or in [this guide from a company that knows a thing or two about torture](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/ettover.htm)).

The nice thing about ETL is that you end up somewhere that feels good. The not-so-nice thing about ETL is that by transforming the data to fit your particular needs, you often lose some degree of detail or utility that was present in the source. On the flip side, if you create a highly generalized data model in order to capture as much of that source data as possible and avoid destructive transformations, you end up with a highly generalized data model, which implies more documentation and maintenance work even if your model is perfect—which it never is.

Now, it sounds like you're either unwilling or unable to *transform* your source data to fit a reasonably focused model. And you **should not** cram it all into one table full of repeating columns and NULLs, lest your rapid descent into madness be punctuated by visions of Cthulhu in his house at R'lyeh:

```
+-----+---------+------------+---------+-----------------+-------------+-----+
| id  | sup1_id | sup1_color | sup2_id | sup2_color      | sup2_weight | ... |
+-----+---------+------------+---------+-----------------+-------------+-----+
| 1   | 7124    | brn        | 93      | Burnt Sienna    | 0.65        | ... |
| 2   | 415     | yel        | 8552    | Bananas Foster  | 12.50       | ... |
| 3   | NULL    | NULL       | 51      | Mostly Red      | 2.00        | ... |
| 4   | 159     | wht        | NULL    | NULL            | NULL        | ... |
| 5   | NULL    | NULL       | NULL    | NULL            | NULL        | NULL NULLNULLNULLUNNLUNUL gratuitous Unicode diacritics, you get the idea
```

That doesn't belong in a relational database at all; it's a flat file/spreadsheet paradigm that should be restricted to non-database environments like Excel. (Or Access. *Zing!*)

What you're left with, if you need to retain the disparate tables in their various forms but still want to *relate* them to one another and keep some kind of "master" record, is creating additional tables to characterize those relationships and store your "one key to rule them all." Now we're heading in the direction of talking about **subtypes and roles**. You have one entity (Product) that's represented in various ways; if each instance of a product exists in exactly one representation, then you're dealing with entity *subtypes*. In the case where there is overlap, as there is here, it's better to think of *roles* that instances can take on with each supplier. Here's an example from [Data Modeling, A Beginner's Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071623981):

[image]

Your "master" ID and any associated information would belong to the relation on the left, which I'll just call Product. This is where you want to store attributes that will always be the same for a given product, no matter the supplier; or, the "official" version of an attribute that you know differs among suppliers, if such is required. For example, if you are a manufacturer, your MSRP for a product does not depend on the retailer carrying the product; it should be in the main table. It may also serve as an "official" price in contrast with the various list prices associated with different retailers.

Your various supplier tables are on the right. These are the roles that a product takes on; here would be stored any information that you want to be able to vary from supplier to supplier (in your example, product color) or that is associated some suppliers and not others (in your example, weight). Since there is a many-to-many relationship between products and roles, you add a junction table between them, where roles are assigned; you don't need to have dates in your junction table, as in the above image, if you're not keeping a history, but that's an example where information *concerning the role assignment* would be appropriate to store in the junction table.

Since you specified that you need to link together records from the supplier tables *after* they're inserted, via your mystery manual process, your workflow under this approach would probably be something like:

1. Records are inserted into various supplier tables.
2. You notice that new records have been inserted (here's where a trigger could be useful).
3. Using your magical mystery manual process, you identify whether each new record does or does not already exist in Product.
4. Whenever a new record from the supplier does not exist in Product, you insert a new row into Product to uniquely identify (and perhaps characterize) that item.
5. You insert a new row into the junction table for each new record from a supplier, linking the unique record for that item to the additional information characterizing it in its role with that supplier.

Note that because your foreign keys will be in the junction table, it's possible to have products with no role/supplier and to have suppliers that carry no products. As for keeping up with the workflow and avoiding mistakes, unless you're prepared to give us much more information about your process for linking products between supplier tables, the best I can suggest is to use `AFTER INSERT` triggers on each of the supplier tables to put the name of the table and the PK of the row into a table that keeps track of new products until they've gone through your manual linking process, and remove these rows as you go through your manual linking process.

You could use another trigger on the junction table to clear the new/unlinked products table but it's riskier to have a trigger updating or deleting rows. In fact, if you can populate your new/unlinked products table using application logic instead of triggers, that might be preferable as well. You can read through the blog [Triggers Considered Harmful, Considered Harmful](http://harmfultriggers.blogspot.com/2011/11/triggers-considered-harmful-considered.html) for a thoughtful analysis of both sides of the trigger debate, though it's not specific to MySQL.

Comment: Thank you very much! I would definitely use the helpful ideas you suggested here. As for my question, I'm not sure which relevant information is unclear. Thanks again.

Comment: As someone who also does this, I agree. There's not enough emphasis on the manual in the answer, but you capture the essential points. I'd describe your "master" record as a "golden" record; the final viewpoint _you_ have on what your suppliers have told you. You have to make the final decision, based on what you know, as to what is "correct". Expect to be wrong occasionally.

Answer (score -1):

I would create a master product table, with your own primary key (id).

```
create table product_master (
product_id INTEGER(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
product_name varchar(512),
...
);
```

Then I would add a new field in each supplier table.

```
alter table a add product_id integer(11);
alter table b add product_id integer(11);
...
```

ideally you define the product_id in product_master table as primary key, and as foreign key in supplier tables.

Populate the product master with the content of the 1st supplier, then via a GUI link each product either to an existing product, or a new product master. Do not forget to create an option to "merge" 2 product master into 1, just in case you realize too late 2 products are actually the same.

If most product are different, you could populate the product master with the content of every supplier, and then use the merge function to merge 2 products.

Merge of product with product_id 45 and 555 means:
1) Update product_id from 45 to 555 in every supplier table where present
2) Delete the entry 555 in product master table

Obviously you need a GUI to perform this task efficiently.

Comment: This is backwards; you should model the "master" table as a weak entity.